# How to improve this OO Python code?

Tags: python, oop

I am a new pythoner, and don not have good knowledge of OOD. I complete the following task, but I feel the code is not good and I don't know how to improve it. Can any one help me?

> You need to create the foundations of an e-commerce engine for a B2C (business-to-consumer) retailer. You need to have a class for a customer
>   called User, a class for items in inventory called Item, and a shopping cart class called Cart. Items go in Carts, and Users have one Carts. but, multiple items can go into Carts, including more than one of any single item.

The code shown as following:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__cart = Cart()

    def BuyGoods(self, gname, gnum, item):
        self.__cart.AddItem(gname, gnum, item)

    def ShowMygoods(self):
        return self.__cart.ShowCart()


class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__Goodslist = {}

    def AddItem(self,goods,goodsnum, item):
        if item.SaleGoods(goods,goodsnum) == 0:        #class interaction
            try:
                self.__Goodslist[goods] += goodsnum
            except:
                self.__Goodslist.update({goods:goodsnum})

    def DelItem(self,goods,goodsnum, item):
        try:
            self.__Goodslist[goods] -= goodsnum

            if self.__Goodslist[goods] < 0:
                self.__Goodslist[goods] += goodsnum
                print "Warnning:there is only %d %s in Cart" % (self.__Goodslist[goods],goods)
                return -1

            elif self.__Goodslist[goods] == 0:
                self.__Goodslist.pop(goods)

            item.AddGoods(goods,goodsnum)   #class interaction
            return 0

        except:
            print "Error:there are no %s in Cart" % (goods)
            return -1

    def ShowCart(self):
        return self.__Goodslist 


class Item(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__itemdict = {}

    #@classmethod
    def AddGoods(self,goodsname,goodsnum):
        try:
            self.__itemdict[goodsname] += goodsnum
        except:
            self.__itemdict.update({goodsname:goodsnum})

    #@classmethod
    def SaleGoods(self,goodsname,goodsnum):
        try:
            self.__itemdict[goodsname] -= goodsnum

            if self.__itemdict[goodsname] < 0:
                self.__itemdict[goodsname] += goodsnum
                print "Warnning:there is only %d %s in Item" % (self.__itemdict[goodsname],goodsname)
                return -1

            elif self.__itemdict[goodsname] == 0:
                self.__itemdict.pop(goodsname)
            return 0

        except:
            print "Error:there are no %s in Item" % (goodsname)
            return -1


    def ShowItem(self):
        return self.__itemdict



if __name__ == '__main__':
    item1 = Item()
    item1.AddGoods('apple', 10)
    item1.AddGoods('pear', 5)
    print "item1 have %s" % item1.ShowItem()


    item2 = Item()
    item2.AddGoods('apple', 10)
    print "item2 have %s" % item2.ShowItem()


    User1 = User()
    User1.BuyGoods('apple', 7, item1)
    print "User1 have: %s" % User1.ShowMygoods()

    print "item1 have %s" % item1.ShowItem()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? If this is working code and you just want suggestions on how to improve it, your question may be more appropriate over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Anyway, regarding the code, I think you may have misunderstood the purpose of the `Item` class. I don't think it's supposed to track the contents of a store's inventory, but rather encapsulate the details of a single item that might be purchased. You're currently only dealing with stings like `"apple"` to represent the items the customer is shopping for, but I think you're supposed to be using an instance of `Item` for each think (or maybe for each kind of thing). An obvious extra attribute for an item (beyond the name) is the price.

Comment: thank you very much. you are right, the item is just represent one thing, and i miss the very important attribute --price. i will correct it.